# Emacs startup warning

Tags: macos, emacs

I am using Emacs for Mac OS X 24.2. 
Once the emacs was stuck and then I kill the process, but when I reopened it, some warnings were showed below：

```
warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID 200.
Using it may cause conflicts. Use it anyway? (y or n)
```

From then on the message shows every time when I open Emacs, so what we should do to fix it? I am really annoyed for that.
By the way, my os is Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: What confuse me every time is that there is not a process PID=200 :( . .desktop file is used by desktop-mode, storing the last time status.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It often happens when your emacs exited accidentally last time. You can try this:

Find and delete this file: `.emacs.desktop.lock`. (This is the value of `desktop-base-lock-name` and can be customized.) It is located in your `user-emacs-directory`, usually `.emacs.d` in your home directory.

Comment: I delete the .emacs.desktop.lock. and it worked out ! the message no longer showed. Thanks :)

Comment: if I don't want emacs to create this lock, what should be done ?

Comment: where .emacs.desktop.lock located?

Comment: @Avatar in `~/.emac.d` directory. If not, you could find it with `find ~ -name '.emacs.desktop.lock'`